# Serverless: can't load lambda function on the AWS using deploy comand

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

I'm new to the serverless framework and I'm taking my first steps using [official documentation](https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-python-packaging/). And I get stuck with deploying to aws

```
y700@jekson:~/projects/awstest/numpy-test$ serverless deploy
Serverless: Packaging service...
Serverless: Excluding development dependencies...
Serverless: Injecting required Python packages to package...

  Serverless Error ---------------------------------------

  User: arn:aws:iam::6644331164204:user/lifeline-s3 is not authorized to perform: cloudformation:DescribeStacks on resource: arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:6644331164204:stack/numpy-test-dev/*

  Get Support --------------------------------------------
     Docs:          docs.serverless.com
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
     Issues:        forum.serverless.com

  Your Environment Information ---------------------------
     Operating System:          linux
     Node Version:              8.10.0
     Framework Version:         1.58.0
     Plugin Version:            3.2.5
     SDK Version:               2.2.1
     Components Core Version:   1.1.2
     Components CLI Version:    1.4.0
```

In an AWS account, I created a user with name **serverless** with AdministratorAccess permission and make him serwerless framework default user (`serverless config credentials`). 
After I also added a new policy with the following permission:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "cloudformation:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Didn't help.

But it's strange that in traceback writing *user/lifeline-s3* and I cant understand where this user came from.

Comment: have you got the aws cli installed on the same machine? If so run `aws configure` and enter the credentials for the serverless user there too.

Comment: @KMo I did what you said, but unfortunately the problem is still

Comment: Try looking in `.aws/credentials` to see if there are more than one set of credentials and if so, which one is set to default.

Comment: @KMo Checking, just one record

Comment: and that one record is set to default?

Comment: @KMo Yes, exacly    .

Comment: I've been successful in deploy using `serverless deploy --aws-profile default` command, but it's still not clear why the standard way not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AWS CLI is picking up credentials from either your shell or your `~/.aws/credentials` file. If you want to Serverless and AWS to use default, add `export AWS_PROFILE=default` to your `.bashrc` or equivalent shell config file.